# Drop request in node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it possible using Node.js and express to drop a request for certain route? I.E. not return a http status or any headers? I'd like to just close the connection.

```
app.get('/drop', function(req, res) {
    //how to drop the request here
});
```

Comment: I am not sure, just wondering. Doesn't `return;` produce the desired result? It sounds logical - simply do nothing with response.

Comment: I don't think return will drop the client request, still pends.

Comment: To drop the connection, you should be able to [`.destroy()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy) the [`.socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_socket) used by the request – `req.socket.destroy()`. This will emulate a "disconnect" rather than a "timeout," as you mentioned in other comments. If you want to prolong the request on the server indefinitely, letting the client eventually choose to timeout, then `return;` or just an empty route handler should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

To close a connection without returning anything, you can either [`end()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/net.html#net_socket_end_data_encoding) or [`destroy()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy_exception) the underlying socket.

```
app.get('/drop', function(req, res) {
  req.socket.end();
});
```

I don't think there's any way to drop the connection at your end but keep the client waiting until it times out (i.e. without sending a `FIN`). You'd perhaps have to interact with your firewall in some way.

Comment: It appears impossible to do any better than `destroy()`, because according to here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Session "...sessions consist of three phases: 1. The client establishes a TCP connection (or the appropriate connection if the transport layer is not TCP). 2. The client sends its request..."

Comment: Oh, but actually, what you said here, "...drop the connection at your end but keep the client waiting until it times out...": You may not be able to *drop* the connection at your end, so-to-speak, but there is `pause()`.

Comment: @Andrew that makes it buffer, forever holding the socket (hopefully it times out eventually). You really don't want to do that. It certainly doesn't close the connection like the question asked.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can.
All you need to do is call the res.end method optionally passing in the status code.

Use one of the following methods:

```
res.end();
res.status(404).end();
```

If you wanted to also set the headers, then you'd use the res.set method.
See below

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Content-Length': '123',
  'ETag': '12345'
})
```

For details have a look here
http://expressjs.com/api.html

Comment: I don't want to return a status code though, I want to drop the request completely. I.E. simulate http timeout.

Comment: Return status code 408, that's a timeout status. When you call res.end, you are ending the request processing.

Answer (score -2):

You could do this wherever you want to close the connection:
`res.end()`