# ExpressJS drop connection

Tags: node.js, express

I'm pretty new to ExpressJS and I need to drop connection with user if the number of failed logins for his ip (stored in database) exceeded maximum allowed number, but I can't find documentation on how to do this. It looks like `server.close()` works, but as I understand, it closes the whole server, not only some connection. So what is the way to drop connection from ExpressJS middleware?

Comment: While it doesn't prevent the user to send data, you can call `res.end` directly, the response will be a "empty" html file, which will have almost the same effect.

Comment: @DrakaSAN thanks, it really works, may be that's just what I need

Comment: I would maybe cookie the client on the final failed attempt, with a date time of when you did it. Then add custom middleware to check that cookie and do as DrakaSAN suggested. It means you can put that middleware in before any more complex request handling, without spamming queries into your DB. The client can block it or manually clear it, if course, so it shouldn't be your only check. Just a thought.

Comment: [If you do not feel like answering anything in response…….](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819771/drop-request-in-node-js-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressJS don`t provide a connection to the browser its just processing a HTTP(S) requests, so there is no way to drop it. The Sockets provides, but a suppose thats not your case.

In this case you can send response with a message like 'The maximum number of login attempts has been reached. Please try again in * minutes.' And maybe hide the login form.

Comment: sure you can, here the nice lib for this: [socket.io](http://socket.io/). But on what purpose do you need sockets?

Comment: I need to close connection with single user based on number of failed logins (from database), and I can't figure out another way now, I would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 4):

A alternative way to "drop" connection is to immediately call `res.end()`, which will send a empty answer.

The only downside is that the request will still go throught any previous middleware, so it can't protect from a DoS attack targeted at your middlewares and will not be as effective as dropping the entire connection is case of a DDoS attack.