# Most efficient way to have nodejs ignore http and https requests -- request.abort()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https

What is the least resource intensive way to have nodejs ignore requests unless they meet a specific criteria in the incoming headers?

For example, if the referer is a specific domain, or the url requested contains a specific code or page, then allow it, otherwise reject with no response and minimized resource utilization / connection tie-ups.

The end result being that the requestor's request is cut off immediately, ties up no connections, sends no response, and to the requestor makes it appear the server does not exist.

Kind of like a firewall does where requests are ignored with no response provided.  A firewall does this, but would like to know **how to do something similar with requests that make it to the nodejs server**,especially if they come in large numbers very rapidly.

Currently using request.end() and connection.destroy() to immediately end the request but is this is the best approach, especially since request.end() sends an empty response.

Is request.abort() a better (more resource efficient) way to handle this situation?

Comment: Probably the most efficient way to do this would be to deploy a separate firewall or separate proxy (like nginx) to do this for you.  You can't really make the endpoint think your server isn't there because a TCP connection has been established before you can even see the headers.  Just closing the socket is likely less work for your server to do than sending an empty response.  But, if this is important, then it's probably something you have to measure a bunch of scenarios to see which is the most efficient for your server when under attack by lots of requests you want to avoid.

Comment: Ok, understood a firewall can do this, but once a request gets to the nodejs server, what is the most efficient way to end it?  I modified the question to be specific on this and also considering using request.abort().

Comment: It's probably something you need to measure yourself in some sort of test harness.  It isn't something many people are going to be just walking about knowing the answer to.  `request.abort()` looks like the most streamlined path (drops all pending data and closes the socket), but you'd have to test it.  Personally, I think I'd deploy nginx on the same box as a proxy for this purpose and let that other process handle the filtering of requests so my nodejs server only has to deal with legit requests.

Comment: Isn't `request.abort()` method only available when you make _outgoing_ request?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51651982/1599699 Try `request.destroy()` or `request.socket.destroy()`