# Express: Do not send response to request

Tags: node.js, express

Is it somehow possible in Express to not respond at all? I don’t want to send a `4xx` or `5xx` in a specific case, but just show the “server did not respond” error (in Chrome it’s the `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`).

```
router.get('/noresponse', (req, res, next) => {
  res.end(); // this will send an empty page with a 200 status
});
```

To clarify: I want a behavior similar to NGINX when “sending” a [`444`](https://httpstatuses.com/444) status. (which does **not** actually **send** a `444` to the client, but cancels the request)

Comment: What are you trying to *achieve* with this?

Comment: You should always return something. Hanging (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) is designed to handle the case the server do not work properly. Send back an appropriate error code. It's like returning `undefined` at the end of a function instead of an well defined error code.

Comment: Ok, point taken. My use case is similar to the following: Multiple domains names can redirect to a central Express instance -- we just accept them per wildcard and manage an internal list of allowed domains and the corresponding actions. In case we have a request from a non-supported domain name, I initially felt it would be “cleaner” to reply with an empty response instead of an error code. Would it be better to send a `404` or similar?

Comment: I would say a 401 Unauthorized ?

Comment: Or maybe 204 No Content ?

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question

Comment: Have a look at this handy chart: http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/  I'd probably go with 410, but that's just me.

Comment: @Paul Good point to indicate that the resource is no longer accessible. wait...

Comment: @TGrif I don't think there's a "best" status code for a missing upstream domain, frankly.  2xx responses are wrong b/c it's clearly not any kind of success.  4xx seem most appropriate because asking for something that's not there is definitely a client mistake (unless the upstream server is broken).  Maybe 418?  :)

Comment: @Paul Absolutely agree. That's why I said "one of". But in this case, OP specificaly want to send empty response. And sure, I'm a big fan of 418 (as an easteregg, most of the time).

Comment: Thanks for all the input (esp. the flowchart, I had seen that a while ago but forgotten about it). At the end a very subjective issue, but I'll probably not overthink this too much and either go for a `403` or `404`. A `2xx` feels wrong in my case, as stated by @Paul.

Comment: Flowchart for choosing a status code: https://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here’s a snippet which does what I was initially aiming for:

```
router.get('/noresponse', (req, res, next) => {
  res.destroy(null);
});
```

However as I find no documentation about its implications and I do not want to work against any best practices I’ll go for a `4xx` response instead.

Comment: Note that this is still not the same. I'm getting "The connection was reset" even though there's technically no "response". If no server was up at all, it would show "Unable to connect" instead.

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to do any better than this though. See my comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51651982/1599699